# decoding a moment generating function

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable with the moment generating function
$$_() =\frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^{\frac{t^2}{2n}}}{n^2}$$
Then $(X\in \mathbb{Q})$, where  is the set of rational numbers, equals

I have been stuck at this problem for a while now. Cant make *any* headway. Any hints?

Comment: should I maybe delete this question now?